# Pycharm - Merge again

Tags: python, django, pycharm

Is it possible to merge to files, one from remote repository, other local, if I've already applied merging?

I can't find any function in Pycharm menu for that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand exactly what your question is.

Look under the VCS menu selection at the top or the Change tab on the bottom.  All merge activities are handled by the built in source code management clients for either Subversion or Git.

I think JetBrains clients for Subversion and Git are top shelf.